# Генерация случайных значений для константных distribution и engine

Tags: c++, const, генерация-случайных-данных

Почему данный код [компилируется](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:21,endLineNumber:9,positionColumn:21,positionLineNumber:9,selectionStartColumn:21,selectionStartLineNumber:9,startColumn:21,startLineNumber:9),source:%27%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0A%23include+%3Cfunctional%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Crandom%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++const+auto+engine+%3D+std::default_random_engine(std::random_device%7B%7D())%3B%0A++++const+auto+distribution+%3D+std::uniform_int_distribution%3Cint%3E(1,+100)%3B%0A++++const+auto+generator+%3D+std::bind_front(distribution,+engine)%3B%0A%0A++++auto+random_values+%3D+std::vector%3Cint%3E(42)%3B%0A++++std::ranges::generate(random_values,+generator)%3B%0A%0A++++for+(const+auto+x+:+random_values)+%7B%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+x+%3C%3C+!%27%5Cn!%27%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.99999999999999,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:g121,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+gcc+12.1+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.99999999999999,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4), хотя оператор `()` является неконстантным как у [distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution/operator()), так и у [engine](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/linear_congruential_engine/operator())?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>


int main() {
    const auto engine = std::default_random_engine(std::random_device{}());
    const auto distribution = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(1, 100);
    const auto generator = std::bind_front(distribution, engine);

    auto random_values = std::vector<int>(42);
    std::ranges::generate(random_values, generator);

    for (const auto x : random_values) {
        std::cout << x << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Очевидно потому, что у объектов `const auto distribution` и `const auto engine` в приведенном коде оператор () не вызывается.

Comment: @user7860670 почему не вызывается? Разве `generator` не вызывает `distribution(engine)`? И он тоже константный

Comment: Не вызывается, потому что в приведенном коде такого нет... Поставьте точку останова в оператор и увидите, у какого объекта и где он вызывается.

Comment: @user7860670 можете объяснить, *что* вызывается тогда? В моём понимании, `std::ranges::generate` помещает в каждый элемент вектора результат вызова `generator()`, который, в свою очередь, вызывает `distribution(engine)`

Comment: Вы почему-то уверены, что в генерации участвуют объекты `const auto distribution` и `const auto engine`, объявленные в функции, а не их копии, созданные при создании `generator`. https://godbolt.org/z/d69Pbeer9

Comment: @user7860670 теперь понятнее, а где и как эти копии хранятся? Если просто по значению в классе, возвращаемом `std::bind_front`, то тогда константный оператор `()` этого класса не должен менять их, если они не `mutable`, а значит всё равно ошибка должна быть, раз этот класс константный. Чтобы не хранить копии, надо передавать `std::ref`?

Comment: В классе, возвращаемом `std::bind_front`, оператор () не обязан иметь const квалификатор.

Comment: @user7860670 ок, но как тогда `std::ranges::generate` умудряется вызывать его, если просто `generator()` выдаёт ошибку?

Comment: Потому что `std::ranges::generate` не вызывает `generator()`... А тоже создает копию. `generator` же передается туда по значению.